# Selenium Webdriver in Internet explorer

Tags: java, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver

I have automated the login functionality using selenium `webdriver` with java and executed it with chrome driver.

It is working fine. Then i tried to execute it with `internet explorer`.

But I'm getting the "**Unable to locate the element**".

How can I solve this issue?

Code:

/* Login without entering username */

@Test(priority = 0)

```
public void loginWithoutUsername() throws InterruptedException {

        int emptyUsernameRowNumber = 1;
        WebElement login = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='main-section']/div/div/section[2]/div[1]/ul/li[1]");
        login.click();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        WebElement username =  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='emailtxt']");
        username.clear();
        username.sendKeys(getCellContent(0, emptyUsernameRowNumber));
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='passwordtxt']");
        password.sendKeys(getCellContent(1, emptyUsernameRowNumber));
        WebElement continueButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='main-section']/div/div/section[2]/div[3]/a/span");
        continueButton.click();     
}
```

HTML:

```
<head>
<body class="game-play game-login">
<div id="page">
<form id="form1" method="post" action="./">
<div class="aspNetHidden">
<script type="text/javascript">
<input id="email_hidden" name="email_hidden" value="2" type="hidden">
<input id="username_hidden" name="username_hidden" value="2" type="hidden">
<input id="profilepath_hidden" name="profilepath_hidden" value="2" type="hidden">
<div class="container fluid">
<div class="content-wrap">
<main id="main-section" class="transition page-in">
<div class="main-content">
<div class="game-login-wrap">
<section class="gme-ply-head">
<section class="center-pin">
<div class="title-head">
<ul class="log-reg clearfix">
<li class="active">Login</li>
<li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="field-input">
<div class="login__row">
<input id="emailtxt" class="login__input email" name="emailtxt" placeholder="Email" type="text">
<span class="log-icon">
</div>
<div class="login__row scn-top">
<input id="passwordtxt" class="login__input pass" name="passwordtxt" placeholder="Password" type="password">
<span class="log-icon">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: which exception you are facing?

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with xpath == //*[@id='main-section']/div/div/section[2]/div[1]/ul/li[1]

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ExplicitWait` to check element is present or not and then do your actions

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 120);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='main-section']/div/div/section[2]/div[1]/ul/li[1]")));

 // Do your actions
```

Comment: The element is clearly visible on the page when the code is executed. Still explicit wait. But no use. I'm getting the same error

Comment: can you add some html and your code snippet because it  hard to judge what is happening

Comment: Code is added with question

Answer (score 0):

Its very often for the xpaths written in chrome to not work with internet explorer.

With the given HTML snippet and assuming the Login wrapped in 'li' tag as your login link, you can try using below xpath:

```
//li[text()='Login']
```